# Is there a better way to inherit window in WPF

Tags: wpf, inheritance, window

In winform, we can inherit easily. But in WPF, we can't inherit class which contains XAML. So whenever I need to generalize some window's attribute, I create a base class without XAML. For example, I want to make all windows start up at center screen. I use code behind in the base class (this class doesn't contain XAML)

```
namespace VBDAdvertisement
{
    public class BaseWindow:Window
    {
        public BaseWindow()
        {
            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        }
    }
}
```

That is just for a simple task. In my opinion, for more complex task, using code behind line by line is not a good idea. So I wonder if there is a better way to inherit window in WPF (something closer to winform inheritance) ?