# c#, wpf - template window?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

Is there anything build in Visual Studio 2013 that allows me to make a template for a wpf window?

I have multiple windows based on the same structure. I have already implemented a interface but I want it to be quiet the same as my template window.

Any clues?

Comment: Can you be more specific? *Structure*? If you mean xaml, then it's duplicate: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7884166/1997232), [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20454202/1997232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Master Pages on WPF.

One of the really great enhancements in ASP.NET was the introduction of master pages. They help developers to create a consistent layout for the pages in an application. Unfortunately, there is no such concept in WPF and XAML.

The goal is to build a simple WPF application with three pages. Each of the pages should consist of three areas:

- Title
- An Abstract
- The main content

Therefore we need a reference to the Master class in our WPF file: `xmlns:m="clr-namespace:MasterPages.Master`". I chose the prefix m for my Master class. With this prefix, I can add a new instance of Master to the page. Inside of  I can set the Title, the Abstract and the Content property of the class.

Original Article: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23069/WPF-Master-Pages)